# php round a float if exists and add comma if needed

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal, rounding, number-formatting

I tried to check similar questions but i didn't get exact same one.So here is what i want

> 3.45678  to 3.46
>
> 3456789 to 3,456,789 //**not 3,456,789.00**
>
> 3456789.45678 to 3,456,789.46

I tried

> number_format($num,2) //it adds 00 at the end
>
> round($num,2) //no comma

If its repeated question i apologize for that and please give me the link

thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just do the first thing you tried, then do a str_replace for '.00'?

Comment: Yes you are right i can use  > str_replace('.00','',number_format($num,2)) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function convertNumber($number) {
    return str_replace('.00', '', number_format($number, $decimals=2, $dec_point='.', $thousands_sep=','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number formatter class can do that for you, plus it supports any ICU locale.

```
<?php

$nf = new NumberFormatter("en_US", \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$nf->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
$nf->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
echo $nf->format($number, \NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this

```
<?php 
     if (is_float($num)) {
       $num=round($num,2);
       echo number_format($num, 2); 
     } 
     else {
       echo number_format($num); 
     }
?>
```